# Get the item with the minimum BigDecimal in list of objects kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following data class

```
data class Info(
  val id: Int = 0,
  val text: String = "",
  val amount: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO
)
```

In my adapter class, I get a `List<Info>`, and I need to find the object with the minimum `amount`.

I tried this:

`val lowestValueInfo = list.find { it.amount.min() }`

Comment: `list.minBy { it.amount }`

Comment: @Nicolas it's deprecated since kotlin 1.4, new function: `minByOrNull`